# How to setup a list with removable items that stores itself in localStorage in javaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, local-storage

I have been working on a little project and I need some values to be stored in an array, that would be displayed at all times, even if the page reloads, and that could be removed by pressing a button.

The idea that I had is to store the array in localStorage, and every time the page loads, they get downloaded into the javascript array. 
That seems to work flawlessly, but my problems come when I am trying to remove them by pressing a button. I know where the problem in my code is, I just don't know how to do it so that it works.

The problem is that, after I delete an item with a low index, it messes with my ability to later delete items with higher index.

Here's the code:

```js
var input = document.getElementById("text");
var displayed = input.value;
var a = [];

function check() {

  if (localStorage.session == null) {
    a.push(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('session')));
    a.splice(0, 1);
    localStorage.setItem('session', JSON.stringify(a));

  }
}

function SaveDataToLocalStorage() {

  a = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('session'));
  if (input.value !== "input") {
    a.push("<p>" + input.value + " </p><button onclick='Delete(" + (a.length - 1) + ")'>Delete</button><br />");
  } else {
    displayed = "";
  }
  localStorage.setItem('session', JSON.stringify(a));
  document.getElementById("Demo").innerHTML = a.join("");
}

function Delete(deleted) {
  var index = deleted;
  a.splice(deleted, 1);
  localStorage.setItem('session', JSON.stringify(a));
  document.getElementById("Demo").innerHTML = a.join("");

}

check();
SaveDataToLocalStorage();
```

```html
<input type="text" name="input" value="input" id="text">
<button onclick="SaveDataToLocalStorage()">Click</button>
<div id="Demo">
```

If anyone could help, It would be Amazing!

Comment: "I know where the problem in my code is" -- ok, where is it?

Comment: Sorry, the problem is that when I delete an Item from the array, the array length I smaller, so for example if I delete number 8 out of 9, the array length is suddenly 8 and 9 is undeletable.

Comment: That sounds like...exactly what you'd want to happen. If you have 9 items and you delete the 8th one, the length would be 8 afterward.

Comment: Yeah, but that was more of an improvised solution that didn't work. What I want is to be able to delete anything anytime. So for example, Delete first 1, then 8, then 6, the 9.

Comment: I think what you want would be to store an array objects instead of an array of raw data so you could store a unique index in each object and fetch them so you can remove them

Comment: With what I have, It is impossible to delete them in random order, because if an item has an "id" if I may call it so, bigger than the array length, it is undeletable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't test the code but I think this can help you out!

```js
var input = document.getElementById("text");
var displayed = input.value;
var a = [];

function check() {
  if (localStorage.session == null) {
    a.push(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('session')));
    a.splice(0, 1);
    localStorage.setItem('session', JSON.stringify(a));
  }
}

function SaveDataToLocalStorage() {
  a = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('session'));
  if (input.value !== "input") {
    a.push({
      index: a.length,
      data: "<p>" + input.value + " </p><button onclick='Delete(" + a.length + ")'>Delete</button><br />"
    });
  } else {
    displayed = "";
  }
  localStorage.setItem('session', JSON.stringify(a));
  document.getElementById("Demo").innerHTML = a.join("");
}

function Delete (deleted) {
  a = a.filter(function (e) { return e.index !== deleted })
  localStorage.setItem('session', JSON.stringify(a));
  document.getElementById("Demo").innerHTML = a.join("");
}

check();
SaveDataToLocalStorage();
```

```html
<input type="text" name="input" value="input" id="text">
<button onclick="SaveDataToLocalStorage()">Click</button>
<div id="Demo">
```

Comment: I apologize that I am replying so late, I just tested it and it only outputs "[object Object]".

Comment: `document.getElementById("Demo").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(a);`

That works, but unfortunately, it displays everything like this:
[{"index":0,"data":"Hello World (Button)
"}.

I may try to work with a.join()...

Comment: Just use `a.data` instead of `a`

Comment: `a[0].data` sorry I forgot the table

Comment: This only displays the first item in the array

Comment: Yeah... So you can use a bit of logic to do the rest ! This is basically an array of object. It's pretty straight forward.

Comment: For loop? That’s what I have in mind. I apologize, I don’t have much knowledge on objects :/

Comment: Anyways, I’m sorry if you facepalm like never before now, I just took an ambitious project that has became more than I can chew :/ I have no OOP knowledge as of right mow, So that may be a big problem

Comment: No problem at all. Everybody has been a beginner! JS is not the easiest language to learn though. So yes, you'd probably get what you whant through a loop (e.g. `a.forEach(function(element) { /*do what you want with element.data*/ })`

Comment: It works great for the SaveDataToLocalStorage function, I've done this:
`for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById("Demo").innerHTML += a[number1].data;
    number1++;
  }`

However, in the Delete function, I cannot get it to work. The only thing That I came up with is to add `location.reload()`
And I don't want it to work like this since it wouldn't really work well with other stuff on the webpage

Comment: `document.getElementById("Demo").innerHTML = "";
  a.forEach(function(item) {
    document.getElementById("Demo").innerHTML += item.data;
  })`

This did the trick for delete and SaveDataToLocalStorage. It works flawlessly now, thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is with this

```
a.push("<p>" + input.value + " </p><button onclick='Delete(" + (a.length - 1) + ")'>Delete</button><br />");
```

You're hardcoding the index to delete in the Delete button, but the index can change if you delete an item from earlier in the array.

You could consider re-rendering everything, including the buttons, every time your array changes.

Another alternative is that every item in your array can have an ID, and that would not change when an earlier one is deleted. Then you can make your 'delete' function remove an element from the array based on its ID.

One more solution: make the button click function *check it's own index* upon click (eg check if it's the 2nd delete button or the 9th delete button), and delete from the array the index that it gets from that check. That way you can keep most of your code the same, but the index isn't hardcoded into the button, it's live-checked every time.

Comment: Those solutions could work. I have to go now, but when I'll get back home, I'll definitely try them. Thank you.